# EditorForTemplate inside a DisplayForTemplate MVC Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I was trying to use Html Display For Template for looping through a Model data. Inside my Display template, I wanted to use an EditorFor template that would display a different set of data, In doing so, I was running into issues where my child model was empty. Upon playing around and getting guidance from David, I was able to make this to work. Below, please find my updated working solution.

**UPDATE (Correct solution)**

```
public class TargetingAreaViewModel
{
    public int DealerId { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public List<TargetingAreaOrderItemViewModel> TargetingAreaOrderItems { get; set; }
    public TargetingAreaViewModel()
    {
        this.TargetingAreaOrderItems = new List<TargetingAreaOrderItemViewModel>(); 
    }
}
public class TargetingAreaOrderItemViewModel
{
    public int OrderItemId { get; set; }
    public int PackageMediaTypeId { get; set; }
    public string PackageMediaTypeHeader { get; set; }
    public string MediaTypeDesc { get; set; }
    public string TargetingAdditonalInfo { get; set; }
    public List<TargetingAreaItemViewModel> TargetingAreaItems { get; set; }
    public TargetingAreaOrderItemViewModel()
    {
        this.TargetingAreaItems = new List<TargetingAreaItemViewModel>();
    }
}
public class TargetingAreaItemViewModel
{
    public int OrderItemId { get; set; }
    public int PackageMediaTargetingFieldId { get; set; }
    public string TargetingAreaFieldTitle { get; set; }
    public string TargetingValue { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
    public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

Parent View

```
@model Models.TargetingAreaViewModel
@{
ApplicationContext.Current.PageTitle = "Targeting Info";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/MainLayout.cshtml";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("OrderItemTargetingInfo", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.TargetingAreaOrderItems)
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="pull-right">
        <input id="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</div>
}
```

DisplayFor Template View

```
@model Models.TargetingAreaOrderItemViewModel
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-sm-12 btn-primary" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px;">
        @Html.Label(Model.MediaTypeDesc, new { @style = "font-weight: bold; padding-top: 10px; font-size: 18px;" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.OrderItemId)
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    @Html.Raw(Model.PackageMediaTypeHeader)
</div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.TargetingAreaItems)
</div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Additional Info:", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.TargetingAdditonalInfo, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Now, I am able to display the data, get the data out of my model on Post. Works great!!

Comment: Can you show us more of your code, there's not enough here to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Post updated above. Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your parent views you are only passing in the `TargetingAreaOrderItems` of the model but the child view is expecting a `TargetingAreaViewModel`. Instead you should pass in the entire model:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m)
```

Comment: When I do that, I get an error here. @Html.Label(Model.MediaTypeDesc, new { @style = "font-weight: bold; padding-top: 10px; font-size: 18px;" })

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks a lot David for guiding me in the right direction. My model was messed up, so after reorganizing it, I was able to achieve what I was looking for. I will update my solution above. Will mark your post as an answer still since it helped me in making the right move.